# Возник баг при редактировании вопроса

Tags: дефект, локализация, правки

Нашёл баг. Создал новый вопрос, удалил сразу же, нажал редактировать, получил это:

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10565/398802